# How can I set alignment in eclipse using xssf

Tags: javascript

I'm using in XSSFWorkbook

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

and then I wanna perform

```
style.setAlignment
```

but it makes an error now.

the goal I have to is only for ***CENTER_ALIGN***, please help me.

Comment: What error it makes? Could you post some sample code that reproduces the error?

Comment: change white text and write line on text and it is not work